# How to make a plane that has been deformed straight?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Currently working on a car for a game and I want it to be low poly kinda like the one below.

[image]

The problem is that I made it using a flat plane and then used the edit mode to move and cruve them into place so now my hood looks like this:

[image]

Please help D: All I want is to make it into a flatter surface with less dents and bumps!

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to start from scratch, your model seems quite messed up. Try [looking into some low poly tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+low+poly+car) on the internet

Comment: In Object Mode setting the Shading to Smooth may help.

Comment: You can select several faces and scale them along normals so that they become equally oriented in 3D space which might fix that model a bit. Although there might be needed quite a bit of manual work to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Try scaling with a value of 0 on an axis, that will straighten it for you.

Maybe try all three axis and see which one will fix it  (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> ), also try the Z and Y as well .

Answer (score 1):

Try Looptools addon, using Flatten with the offending faces selected.